# How to set default value for single select drop-down of select2 through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-select2

I'm trying to set default select value of select2 options but it was not working ...can anyone help me .?

here is my controller

```
 public ActionResult OrderAcceptanceDetails()
    {
        var res = Db.CustomerDetails.ToList();
        Session["cust"] = new SelectList(res, "CUSTCODE", "CUSTCODE");
        var yearlist = Db.Years.ToList();
        Session["year"] = new SelectList(yearlist, "Year1", "Year1");
        //var spresult = Db.Database.SqlQuery<OADetail>("Sp_OADetails_GetAll").ToList<OADetail>();
        return View();
    }
```

here is my view

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <p>
                @Html.DropDownList("Year", Session["year"] as SelectList, "-- Select Year-- ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "selectpicker", data_style = "select-with-transition" })
            </p>
        </div>
```

here is my javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Year").children("option:last-child").attr("selected",trues);
            })
            </script>
```

i want to select last child of dropdown value which are come from database.please tell me how's this possible.?

Comment: `trues` != `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the trigger property for this:
[doc](https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35#deprecated-and-removed-methods)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Year").select2({ width: '75px' });
  $("#Year").children("option:last-child").attr("selected", true).trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="Year">
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
</select>
```